# Unselect all accessory checkmarks when clicked on a cell with specific title

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView which shows a list of selectable options. One of the cells title is "Other" and the other is "None of above".

When I click on "other" I want a text box to be displayed in the cell and accept text. after returning from the text box the cells title should be replaced with the entered text.

when I click on "None of the above", I want all the accessoryType of cells to be .none.

```
struct SelectedOptions : Codable {
    var title : String = ""
    var isChecked : Bool = false
}

var options = SelectedOptions()

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

 //   if selectedOptionsList[indexPath.row].isChecked == true {
        if ((cell?.textLabel?.text == "Other") && selectedOptionsList[indexPath.row].isChecked == true) {
            //1. Create the alert controller.
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Please enter other condition.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
            alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                //textField.text = "Some default text"
            }

            // 3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
                let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
                self.selectedOptionsList[34].title = textField?.text ?? "Other"
                tableView.reloadData()
                print("Text field: \(textField?.text)")
            }))

            // 4. Present the alert.
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if((cell?.textLabel?.text == "None of these conditions apply to me at this time.") && selectedOptionsList[indexPath.row].isChecked == true){
            for var condition in selectedOptionsList[0..<35]{
                condition.isChecked = false

                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

I am displaying a textfield in alert to get the text input and replacing that text at the indexpath.

However, for "none of the above" even though I am updating my isChecked condition for all the titles except for none of above.

Comment: You mention you have a list of selectable options. To confirm (please don’t respond to comment, edit your question to include the additional information), you have only two selectable options / cells in your table view?

Comment: please include your cellForRow method, so that we can better understand,
also, could you please provide an image of the buggy/correct behavior?